# Create an array from a list of coordinates and diameter of spheres

Tags: python, arrays, image, list

I have an image 3D with somes spheres included in a box (the dimensions of the box is NxNxN voxels).

**`The list of spheres = [diameter (float), array(x, y, z)] with in (x, y, z) are coordinates of spheres.`**

Now I want to create an array `S` of dimension `NxNxN`. Element `S[i][j][k]` of `S` takes value

- **0** (if point `S[i][j][k]` is out of the sphere)
- **1** (if not)

How could I do that?

Now, I will color theses spheres with yellow or red. I want to do the same thing but this time, 1 for yellow sphere and 2 for red sphere.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any code? You can easily check if a voxel `(x,y,z)` is in `any` of the spheres, based on distance to the centre of each sphere. Do you have rules for colouring them?

Comment: I don't have any rules for coloring them, but the color of spheres will be added in the list before [diameter (float), array(x, y, z), color].

Comment: Again, then, do you have any code? What have you tried so far? What step are you stuck on? This isn't a place to get code written for you. Also, do the spheres overlap, and what should happen for vowels in the overlap?

Answer (score 2):

You should really share some code with your questions, to show us what have you tried and why is not working. The community will be much more helpful if they see your efforts. But since this was kind of an easy problem and I was in a mood for that right now, I coded a solution for you:

```
# init
n = 7
range_n = range(n)
box = [[[0 for x in range_n] for y in range_n] for z in range_n]
spheres = [
    {"color": 1, "diameter": 2.0, "x": 4, "y": 1, "z": 2},
    {"color": 2, "diameter": 1.5, "x": 3, "y": 4, "z": 5}
]

# is a point inside a sphere?
def point_in_sphere(x, y, z, sphere):
    return (x - sphere["x"])**2 + (y - sphere["y"])**2 + (z - sphere["z"])**2 <= sphere["diameter"]**2

# union
for z in range_n:
    for y in range_n:
        for x in range_n:
            color = 0
            for sphere in spheres:
                if point_in_sphere(x, y, z, sphere):
                    color = sphere["color"]
            box[z][y][x] = color

# print
for z in range_n:
    for y in range_n:
        print " " * (n - y),
        for x in range_n:
            print box[z][y][x],
        print
    print
```

I belive this is doing what you want, it even prints the box at the end, so you can verify the results. Output:

```
        0 0 0 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 0 1 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0

        0 0 0 1 1 1 0
       0 0 0 1 1 1 0
      0 0 0 1 1 1 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0

        0 0 0 1 1 1 0
       0 0 1 1 1 1 1
      0 0 0 1 1 1 0
     0 0 0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0

        0 0 0 1 1 1 0
       0 0 0 1 1 1 0
      0 0 0 1 1 1 0
     0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0
   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0

        0 0 0 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 0 1 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 2 0 0 0
    0 0 2 2 2 0 0
   0 0 0 2 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0

        0 0 0 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 2 2 2 0 0
    0 0 2 2 2 0 0
   0 0 2 2 2 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0

        0 0 0 0 0 0 0
       0 0 0 0 0 0 0
      0 0 0 0 0 0 0
     0 0 0 2 0 0 0
    0 0 2 2 2 0 0
   0 0 0 2 0 0 0
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I don't write any code because I use ImageJ, so I can create a binary image from the original one.